# precondition failing for deployment of storage account

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-deployment, azure-bicep

I am trying to deploy storage account which is getting deployed succesfully first time but when I try to re-deploy it ,it fails and complains about default blob deployment pre-condition failed for following section of the bicep template

```
resource blob_default 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-04-01' = {
    name: 'default'
    parent: stg
    properties: {
      changeFeed: {
        enabled: true
      }
      restorePolicy : {
        enabled: true
        days: 6
      }
      containerDeleteRetentionPolicy: {
        enabled: true
        days: 7
      }
      cors: {
        corsRules: []
      }
      deleteRetentionPolicy: {
        enabled: true
        days: 7        
      }
      isVersioningEnabled: true
    }
}
```

this child blob resource is part of storage account deployment template and it is failure cause in overall deployment of storage account with error message

> {
> "status": "Failed",
> "error": {
> "code": "ContainerOperationFailure",
> "message": "The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not
> met.\nRequestId:5d03a3d7-e01e-0052-65d4-a8f390000000\nTime:2021-09-13T19:20:18.8705109Z"
> } }

Comment: have you checked deployments errors from azure portal ?

Comment: also the name should be: name: '${storageAccountName}/default'

Comment: Are you deploying the storage and the blo service in the same bicep file ?

Comment: @Thomas yes I am deploying storage account and blob service '${storageAccountName}/default'  in same bicep file. strange part is it is very inconsistent as sometime while deploying it works and sometimes it complains that "message": "The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met

Comment: did you check the deployment errors from azure portal ?

Comment: could you share the whole bicep file please ? I mean at least the storage account part.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same problem. Sometimes deployments work, sometimes they fail with "The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met". It stated a few days ago. Perhaps it is a bug?